# Dual booting Linux-Mint with Windows 10, UEFI/Legacy problem

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot, grub, uefi

I used [this tutorial](https://itsfoss.com/guide-install-linux-mint-16-dual-boot-windows/) to install Linux Mint in a Windows OS Dell computer.

I quickly found that in order to get into Linux I had to hit <kbd>F12</kbd> everytime the computer booted, and then, select boot from USB flashdrive under UEFI booting.

Now, I wasn't aware that this would become a problem, but Windows OS is under legacy booting.

From [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125494/cant-boot-without-flash-drive-plugged-in?newreg=e1402c0bd0bd4e928de74c2d7156e63c), it appears the problem is that Grub was installed onto the flash drive and not onto the internal hard drive. The solution given is

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

When I do this last step (`boot-repair`), I'm getting the error

> LegacyWindows detected. Please enable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy
> mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or
> live-USB)

So, I tried disabling UEFI booting as shown [here](https://www.top-password.com/knowledge/disable-UEFI-enable-legacy-support.html), but I'm still getting the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I never intended to spend so much time just getting Linux to run on a Dell...

Could I reinstall Linux and instead of choosing a partition, choose to wipe the disk to install just Linux, then re-partition the drive in Linux and install a Windows OS in UEFI booting mode so that both are in UEFI?

Comment: You always want all systems installed in same boot mode, or all UEFI or all BIOS. Windows also requires MBR partitioning for BIOS boot and gpt partitioning for UEFI boot. That conversion will erase drive, although there are ways to convert that may save data. But Windows also requires significantly different partitioning. You can install Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode, but if hardware is UEFI, better to use UEFI. Be sure to have good backups.  Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI boot mode since Windows 8 released in 2012. Windows 7 systems before then were usually BIOS.

Comment: You're also better off installing Windows first (with custom partitioning, maybe done beforehand) _and_ Linux last so that you get GRUB bootmanager with both of those.
Возможно, пригодится что-то с http://altlinux.org/UEFI